# DataGridView.Sort first Row Bug?

Tags: c#, sorting, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

Hei, I write an String into the DataGridView in the first Column, then I want to Sort this but there is always a Problem because this Method doesn't affect the first row..

I don't know why this happens but every time I try it writing different things into the Array the same Problem appears again.

Here is my Code which throws this weird seeing Problem to me, maybe you guys can fix it?

```
public void namenEintrag(string[] name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = name[i];
        }

        dataGridView1.Sort(dataGridView1.Columns[0], ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    }
```

And this is the File from which the Array has the Names (changed for this Post)

```
Laura, Becker
Jessica, Maur
Laura, Holzman
Dominik, Urner
Martina, Schweitzer
Kristin, Hoffmann
Kerstin, Herman
Paul, Eisenberg
Marko Baumgaertner
Paul, Bayer
Matthias, Nussbaum
```

And now what it looks like in the DataGridView

```
Laura, Becker
Dominik, Urner
Jessica, Maur
Kerstin, Herman
Kristin, Hoffmann
Laura, Holzman
Marko Baumgaertner
Martina, Schweitzer
Matthias, Nussbaum
Paul, Bayer
Paul, Eisenberg
```

Thanks for helping my stupid me.

Edit:  This is my Code to create the Table:

```
public void tabelle()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("Tabelle");

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Namen:"));

        for (int i = 1; i <= spalten; i++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(i.ToString()));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < namen.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();

            for (int j = 1; j < spalten; j++)
            {
                dr[j] = "";
            }

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

And what I forgot to mention is, that when I click somewhere on the Table it sorts it in the right order, but not at the Start of the Program...

Comment: Just a thing to check; there isn't any white space (spaces) at the beginning of `Laura, Becker` is there?

Comment: no, it starts right away with `Laura, Becker`

Comment: How do you create the rows to start with? "dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value" updates an existing row

Comment: @MartW I edited my Post, you can find the Code to create the Rows above

Comment: you should try to assign "name[I]" to the datatable not to the cells of the grid